# Azure DevOps automatically updated node/npm version - can this be avoided?

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

On 1st Dec 2021 (a couple of days ago at time of writing) Azure DevOps seemingly automatically upgraded the version of node and npm they were using by default, which broke our build pipelines.

**before: 2021-11-30T15:30:01.113Z**

[image]

**after: 2021-12-01T09:00:00.450Z**

[image]

(no changes were made to these build pipelines in between)

I have manually set the version in a 'Node.js tool installer' step in the pipeline now ([as suggested here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/javascript?view=azure-devops&tabs=code&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511#troubleshooting)).

Can this automatic upgrade be avoided or is there a website or email newsletter I am missing that informs Azure DevOps users when Microsoft upgrade versions they are using behind the scenes?

Answer (score 8):

Microsoft will automatically maintain the images for the hosted pipelines. Node 6 is no longer supported by the Node foundation and has known security issues. Microsoft automatically upgrades these kinds of dependencies in these cases to keep the image "secure". **There is no opt-out**, unless you run self-hosted agents in your own hardware/cloud subscription.

You can track the [announcements](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues?q=label%3AAnnouncement+), [work in progress](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/commits/main) and [the releases of the agent images in the virtual-environments repository](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/releases). The same images are used for Azure Pipelines as for GitHub Actions.

Bigger changes (such as the deprecation of the windows-2016 image are also announced on the [Microsoft DevOps Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511).

To force an older version of Node/Npm than the default, you'll need to add the Node Tool Installer task to your workflow and set the version to the one you want:

```
task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '6.x'
```

Or:

```
task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
```

You can always run a custom `npm -g npm@^6` to force npm to upgrade/downgrade.

Comment: The issue is about npm@6, not about node@6. 

npm@6 is bundled with node@14, and node@14 has not reached end-of-life by far(planned for 2023-04-30). The current stable version is node@16 with npm@8, and npm@8 has serious breaking changes compared to npm@6.

Is it not possible to configure a specific version of node and npm in Azure?

Comment: The specific announce was made here; https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/4446 You can pin the node version using the NodeTool task.

Comment: having same issue and following this, setting versionspec to 14.x resolved issue for me